# Putting two buttons next to each other with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I was coding a GUI with the Tkinter library in Python and I've ran into the following problem:

```
# DECLARATIONS
labelPresentation = Label(window, text="Insert here")
name = StringVar()
nameEntered = Entry(window, width=25, textvariable=name)
labelPresent = Label(window)
research = ttk.Button(window, text="Search", command=searchToPut)

elimination = ttk.Button(window, text="Delete", command=searchToDelete)

# POSITIONS
labelPresentation.grid(column=0, row=0)
nameEntered.grid(column=0, row=1)
labelPresent.grid(column=0, row=3)
research.grid(column=0, row=2)

elimination.grid(column=0, row=2)
```

I need to put the elimination and research button next to each other but the grid function is causing me problems, because this code put them one in top of the other. I searched for the same problem and they suggested to use the pack() function, but when I try it it says that I can't use both grid and pack function to place buttons and labels. 
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Put the two buttons in a frame.

Comment: @pen00 Can you please share more of your code so we can run it and test it?

Comment: ***causing me problems, because this code put them one in top of the other.***: This is because you use the same Grid coordinates, `grid(column=0, row=2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# DECLARATIONS
labelPresentation = Label(window, text="Insert here")
name = StringVar()
nameEntered = Entry(window, width=25, textvariable=name)
labelPresent = Label(window)
research = ttk.Button(window, text="Search", command = searchToPut)

elimination = ttk.Button(window, text="Delete", command =searchToDelete )

# POSITIONS
#labelPresentation.grid( row=0)
labelPresentation.place(x=50)
nameEntered.place(x=0,y=20)
labelPresent.grid( row=0)
research.grid(row=2,column=0)

elimination.grid(row=2, column = 1 , padx=0,pady = 25)
```

**Output:**

[image]